# Быстрый запуск программы через CMD

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cmd

Подскажите, что нужно сделать, что бы программу можно было запустить по имени через консоль?

Например, если написать в CMD слово Skype, то запускается Skype.

Comment: самый наверно простой вариант - добавить путь к программе в переменную среды PATH, насколько правильно это не знаю.

Comment: @pavel: Это по идее не очень хорошо. В каталоге с программой могут находиться другие исполняемые файлы, и внезапно они все станут доступны без указания пути. Это наверное не вполне правильно.

Comment: Создайте папку, которую добавьте в PATH, а в эту папку кладите батники на программы. Тогда лишних ехешников доступно не будет

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Когда вы пишете команду в консоли, она ищется в директориях из переменной окружения PATH.

Варианта всего два.

Или добавить директорию с программой в PATH - или положить программу в ту директорию, которая уже есть в PATH.

Comment: Только в корне или еще и в поддиректориях?

Comment: @iluxa1810 с чего бы оно в поддиректориях искало?

Answer (score 10):

Рекомендованный Microsoft способ — [ключ реестра App Paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx). При вводе имени программы она ищется в рабочем каталоге, в каталогах `Windows` и `Windows\System32`, в каталогах, перечисленных в переменной окружения `PATH`, и в ключе реестра `App Paths`.

Для регистрации только у текущего пользователя применяйте ключ

```
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
```

Для глобальной регистрации используйте тот же путь, но в `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

Пусть ваша программа называется `myapp.exe`. Создайте вложенный ключ `myapp.exe` в `App Paths`. Поместите `(Default)`-значение типа `REG_SZ`, содержащее полный путь к приложению. Вы можете также указать другие параметры запуска приложения здесь. Например, вы можете сделать так, чтобы к значению переменной окружения `PATH` при запуске вашей программы добавлялись интересующие вас каталоги.

Код на C#:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace AppPathRegistration
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.FirstOrDefault() == "/install")
                Install();
            else
                Run();
        }

        const string appPathsName = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths";

        static void Install()
        {
            var name = "lalafa.exe";
            var path = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
            using (var appPaths = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(appPathsName))
            using (var subkey = appPaths.CreateSubKey(name))
                subkey.SetValue(null, path);
        }

        static void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test application, press any key to finish...");
            Console.ReadKey(intercept: true);
        }
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что имя, которое вы регистрируете, вовсе не обязано совпадать с именем вашей программы.

Об остальных возможностях смотрите [официальную документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx#appPaths).

---

Ключ реестра `App Paths` принимается во внимание при запуске программ посредством функций `Sh­ellExecute`/`Sh­ellExecuteEx`. `CreateProcess` в реестр не подглядывает, и перенаправление не найдёт. Но оболочка Windows и командная строка используют именно shell-функции.

---

Вот [немного истории этого ключа](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110725-00/?p=10073) (на английском).