# Как запустить свой exe в командной строке без указания полного пути?

Tags: c#

К примеру, в командной строке достаточно написать "calc" и Enter, как появляется на экране калькулятор. Как сделать так, чтобы мой exe стал таким же "родным" как calc.exe? Т.е. после указания имени моего exe в командной строке осуществился запуск моей программы (Пример на скрине)? И еще попутно вопрос.Можно ли как-то узнать откуда стартанул мой exe? Именно не полный путь, где установлен, а именно как в примере на скрине "С:\Users\Александр". Т.е. запускаю ехе и в самой программе получаю именно этот путь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавить каталог, в котором хотите делать поиск, в переменную среды Path. Мой компьютер -- свойства -- дополительные параметры системы -- дополнительно -- переменные среды.

Comment: Сейчас исправлю

Comment: Загляните сюда: [Run .exe anywhere in cmd without PATH variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32794991/5275890)

Comment: @DenisBubnov О, интересный способ - не знал, что так можно. Ответом?

Comment: откуда стартанул мой exe - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Igor, то что нужно по второй части вопроса

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рекомендованный Microsoft способ — [ключ реестра App Paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ee872121.aspx).

В ключе реестра

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
```

(для текущего юзера) или

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
```

положите подключ `MyEXE.exe`, а в его значение по умолчанию `(Default)` типа `REG_SZ` поместите полный путь к приложению. Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/575092/10105) есть код, который сделает это за вас.

---

Проблем у `PATH` довольно много. Он добавляет к поиску не один файл, а целый каталог. На длину переменной PATH есть установленный лимит, и он может легко исчерпаться. Установка PATH в программах наследуется, а значит, если одна из программ поменяет PATH, то изменения будут видны некоторых приложениям, а некоторым нет.

Answer (score 6):

Пути, по котором ищутся программы, задаются переменной `path`. В Windows есть две таких переменных - общесистемная и текущего пользователя. Так же можно для конкретного сеанска консоли изменить эти переменные командой (обращаю внимание, что кавычек нет, несмотря на пробелы в имени:

```
set path c:\my magic folder;%path%
```

Если надо узнать значение, то можно просто ввести

```
D:\Temp\Supertemp>set path
```

Чтобы найти программу, надо использовать команду `where`:

```
D:\Temp\Supertemp>where calc
C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe

D:\Temp\Supertemp>where node
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

D:\Temp\Supertemp>where webpack
C:\Users\Qwert\AppData\Roaming\npm\webpack
C:\Users\Qwert\AppData\Roaming\npm\webpack.cmd
```

Если вариантов несколько, обычно (если все программы `exe`) выполняется первый из списка. В случае с разными расширениями ситуация сложнее и начинает использоваться переменная `pathext`.

Comment: В контексте .NET, возможно, стоит упомянуть про метод `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`

Comment: @Андрей, во-первых, я что-то про него сам не в курсе, а во-вторых, консоль-то не в .net.

Comment: Ну дык может автор инсталлятор пишет...

Comment: @Андрей, ну так напиши свой ответ?

Comment: Не, я сплю: -_- zzz