# Помогите с кодом

Tags: c#

Я написал обычный калькулятор, работающий в консоли. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы, например, при записи в консоль слова "Калькулятор" заработал сам калькулятор (изначально он не должен работать).

Вот код:

```
char again = 'д';
while(again=='д')
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double total;
    char oper;

    Console.WriteLine("Введите первое число:");
    a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Введите оператор:");
    oper = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Введите второе число:");
    b = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    if (oper == '+')
    {
        total = a + b;
        Console.WriteLine("Cумма " + a + " и " + b + " равна " + total + ".");
    }

    else if (oper == '-')
    {
        total = a - b;
        Console.WriteLine("Разность " + a + " и " + b + " равна " + total + ".");
    }

    else if (oper == '*')
    {
        total = a * b;
        Console.WriteLine("Умножение " + a + " на " + b + " равно " + total + ".");
    }

    else if (oper == '/')
    {
        total = a / b;
        Console.WriteLine("Деление " + a + " на " + b + " равно " + total + ".");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Неизвестный оператор.");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Вы хотите продолжить работу с калькулятором? (д/н)");
    again = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: Скомпилируйте приложение и назовите исполняемый файл "калькулятор.exe", добавьте в переменную среды PATH путь до этого исполняемого файла.

Comment: Зашли за помощью - помогите и Вы будущим посетителям: заголовок сейчас ничего не говорит о задаче

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575040/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-cmd/575043